# 1/998001 what is sou special about it?

Tags: arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is special about the numbers 9801, 998001, 99980001 ..?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102682/what-is-special-about-the-numbers-9801-998001-99980001)

Why does 1/998001 results in :

0.00000100200300400500600700800900100110120130140150160170...
And it goes on and on till 998999.

What is so special about that ?

[wolframalpha calculation...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/998001)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102682/what-is-special-about-the-numbers-9801-998001-99980001

Comment: It actually goes up to $\ldots995996997$ but misses $998$ and continues $999000001002\ldots$