# What does $\frac{1}{9801}$ equal to?

Tags: decimal-expansion, pattern-recognition

While playing on my calculator I accidentally calculated $\frac{1}{9801}$ and the value was $0.00010203040506070809101112131415161718192021222324252627282930\ldots$
We observe that there is a nice pattern in the decimal expansion.
but how long will it continue ie. after how many digits will it repeat?

Comment: [Ask your son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler's_theorem).

Comment: @CountIblis he couldn't that's why i asked here

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan which one?

Comment: It actually repeats all $2$ digit numbers, starting from $00$ to $99$, excluding $98$.

Comment: It may be but it was difficult to find it using the title and the questions are actually different

Comment: Repeating patterns in decimal expansions are oftend denoted, e.g. $1/3=0.333333\cdots=0.\dot{3}$, or e.g. $1/13=0.07692307692\cdots=0.\dot{0}7692\dot{3}$.

Comment: By the way, $9801=99^2$. It is the only square number with this property.

Comment: @user477343 that's how i got it

Comment: @user477343 $\frac{1}{81}=\frac{1}{9^2}=0.12345679012345679$...

Comment: $9801$ dooesn't it appear in a famous Ramanujan formula?

Comment: @EnzoCreti which formula?

Comment: @Euler's Dad the famous formula for $\pi$...if you google you will find it

Comment: @EnzoCreti yeah that's an amazing formula

Comment: @EnzoCreti the formula is seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series) and graphed by me [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pdpgfqt1tl)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a numberphile video related to this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daro6K6mym8).

Essentially notice that $9801=99^2$. A similar pattern happens with $\frac{1}{9^2}=\frac{1}{81}$. It's value is $0.\dot{0}1234567\dot{9}$, cycling through all the units except $8$ (To see why, try a long division method). The case with $\frac{1}{99^2}$, it cycles through every two digit number, but excludes $98$ from this list... i.e. it is:
$$\frac{1}{99^2}=0.\dot{0}0010203040506\cdots9596979\dot{9}$$ and similar things happen with $\frac{1}{999^2},\frac{1}{9999^2}$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Every fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ with integers $a$ and $b$ has a pattern which continues endlessly.

Comment: Discounting zeros, 1/4=0.25 does not continue forever. But if you count zeros then 1/4=0.250000...

Answer (score 0):

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F9801

See for yourself. A fraction when converted to decimal will repeat at some point of times.

Here it repeats till 99 skipping 98 and then start all over again.

Comment: Incorrect. It skips 98.

Comment: Yup. Sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that with $a \in N$

$$
\frac{1}{9801}=\frac{a}{10^n}(1+10^{-n}+10^{-2n}+\cdots) = \frac{a}{10^n}\frac{1}{1-10^{-n}}
$$

or

$$
a = \frac{10^n-1}{9801}
$$

which gives $n = 198$ and $a = 10203040506070809101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373\\
83940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970717273747
5767\\
7787980818283848586878889909192939495969799$