# Period of the decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{9801}$

Tags: power-series, decimal-expansion

I have to show that $\frac{1}{9801}= 0.\overline{000102030405060708\dots9799}$. Here bar denotes Period.

**My Attempt:** I have shown $\frac{1}{9801}= {0.000102030405060708........9799.........}$ using the power series expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$. But I can not find the period of the decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{9801}$.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: It should divide $\varphi(9801)$

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?@J.W.Tanner

Comment: Isn’t the period just $99\cdot2,$ based on this decimal expansion?

Comment: It would be good if you put in your question the steps you used to show the statement desired using that power series.

Comment: I did not get you. Can you please elaborate ?@ThomasAndrews

Comment: $\frac{1}{9801}=\frac{1}{1-2\cdot100+100^2}$ and use Taylor.

Comment: sani:  In general, the [length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Totient_rule) of the decimal repetend of $1/n$ divides $φ(n)$, but in this particular case I think @ThomasAndrews' comment is more helpful

Comment: You write: "Here bar denotes Period." From the Wikipedia article referred to in @j-w-tanner's comment: "The infinitely repeated digit sequence is called the **repetend** or **reptend**." So, are you using "period" to mean "repetend"?

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is an integer $\geqslant3,$ and $S$ is the sequence
$0,1,2,\ldots,n-3,n-1,$ then the base $n$ expansion of the fraction
$1/(n-1)^2$ is $(.\overline{S})_n,$ because:
\begin{align*}
(n-1)^2(.\overline{S})_n &=
(n-1)^2\left(\frac1{n^2}+\frac2{n^3}+\cdots+\frac{n-3}{n^{n-2}}+
\frac{n-1}{n^{n-1}}\right)
\left(1+\frac1{n^{n-1}}+\frac1{n^{2n-2}}+\cdots\right) \\ &=
(n-1)\left(\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}+\cdots+\frac1{n^{n-3}}+
\frac2{n^{n-2}}-\frac{n-1}{n^{n-1}}\right)
\left(1-\frac1{n^{n-1}}\right)^{-1} \\ &=
(n-1)\left(\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}+\cdots+\frac1{n^{n-3}}+
\frac{n+1}{n^{n-1}}\right)
\left(\frac{n^{n-1}}{n^{n-1}-1}\right) \\ &=
\left(1-\frac1{n^{n-3}}+\frac{n^2-1}{n^{n-1}}\right)
\left(\frac{n^{n-1}}{n^{n-1}-1}\right) \\ &=
\frac{n^{n-1}-n^2+n^2-1}{n^{n-1}-1} \\ &= 1.
\end{align*}

Taking $n=100,$ we get:
$$
1/9801 =
(.\overline{00,01,02,\ldots,97,99})_{100} =
.\overline{00010203\ldots95969799},
$$
so $1/9801$ has period 198 in base $10.$

[But see my comment on the meaning of the word "period" in the question.]

Comment: With hindsight, it would have been tidier to write:
\begin{align*}
(n-1)^2\left(\frac1{n^2}+\frac2{n^3}+\cdots+
\frac{n-3}{n^{n-2}}+\frac{n-1}{n^{n-1}}\right) &=
(n-1)\left(\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}+\cdots+\frac1{n^{n-3}}+
\frac2{n^{n-2}}-\frac{n-1}{n^{n-1}}\right) \\ &=
(n-1)\left(\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}+\cdots+\frac1{n^{n-3}}+
\frac{n+1}{n^{n-1}}\right) \\ &=
1-\frac1{n^{n-3}}+\frac{n^2-1}{n^{n-1}} = 1-\frac1{n^{n-1}}.
\end{align*}
In particular, taking $n=100$:
$$
9801\times.00010203\ldots95969799 =
.\underbrace{99999999\ldots99999999}_{198 \text{ digits}}.
$$

Comment: Alternatively, but really quite similarly: if $n\geqslant3,$ then
\begin{align*}
n^{n-1}-1&=(n-1)\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}n^j\\&=
(n-1)\bigg[(n-1)+\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}(n^j-1)\bigg]\\&=
(n-1)^2\bigg[1+\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}n^k\bigg]\\&=
(n-1)^2\bigg[1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n-2}n^k\bigg]\\&=
(n-1)^2\bigg[1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}(n-k-2)n^k\bigg]\\&=
(n-1)^2\bigg[(n-1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}(n-k-2)n^k\bigg].
\end{align*}
For example, $999999999=81\times12345679.$ The point is that the
expansion of $1/(n-1)^2$ in base $n$ follows from the above identity
which only involves integers.